# Webpack breaking ScrollReveal javascript?

Tags: javascript, webpack, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 6.4.3 with the ZURB Template. For some reason I cannot get the ScrollReveal javascript to work. I always get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: ScrollReveal is not defined`. When I load ScrollReveal from an external URL it works. However, once Foundation runs it through whatever its doing (babel, webpack, whatever) it adds a bunch of webpack related stuff to the ScrollReveal.js. I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is breaking or what I'm doing wrong. I have tried so many different things.

You can see the difference between the original ScrollReveal.js and what happens to it once its ran through Gulp, webpack, babel, etc here:

https://www.diffchecker.com/NUPl2t0I

My Foundation app.js file looks like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import whatInput from 'what-input';


window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = $;

require('./scrollreveal.js');

//also tried this which does not seem to work either..
//import ScrollReveal from 'scrollreveal';


import './lib/foundation-explicit-pieces';
```

And the JS I have on my page looks like this:

```
$(document).foundation().ready(function(){   
    window.sr = ScrollReveal({ reset: true });
    sr.reveal('.people-image', {opacity: 0.9,duration:3000});
});
```

Not really sure where I'm going wrong and what's causing the `ScrollReveal is not defined` error.

Answer (score 0):

In your config.yml file you need to write this under sass:

```
sass:
- "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss"
- "node_modules/motion-ui/src"
- "node_modules/scrollreveal/src"
```

and in your app.js I write:

```
import ScrollReveal from 'scrollreveal'
```

Try: npm install again in your terminal,
That should make it work!